You need to determine whether the session is blocked in Linux
It turned out to determine the session lock in KDE:
to get the session number:
loginctl show-user myuser --property=Display

to get the blocking status:
gdbus call -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 -o /org/freedesktop/login1/session/" + session_number + " -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get org.freedesktop.login1.Session LockedHint

But this no longer works in Cinnamon. I tried to filter by process name. It turned out to be quite simple: ps aux and dropout by cinnamon-screensaver but the latter hangs in the memory for some time after unlocking. Unreliable. I would like to find a universal method
